# How to improved the performance of a 3D resampling with better used of subregion

Tags: python, performance, math, scipy, affinetransform

I have a 3D array of shape (x, y, z) filled with zeros, except for a specific index along the z-axis where it contains non-zero values. I would like to perform a resampling operation to change its size to (x', y', z'). Currently, I have an affine transformation matrix and I'm using the scipy.ndimage.affine_transform() function with order=1 for linear interpolation. However, the performance is not optimal.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this resampling operation given the zero-filled nature of the array and the presence of non-zero values at a specific index? How can I improve the performance of the resampling process while having the same results than doing the resampling on all the array?

This is a summary of the code that I am using, and that I believe can be improved

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import affine_transform
import timeit

# Define the original array dimensions
original_shape = (174, 174, 50)

# Define the desired resampled array dimensions
resampled_shape = (112, 112, 70)

# Create the transformation matrix
transform_matrix = np.array([[1.81250001e+00, -3.69390952e-16, -1.34252262e-18, -8.57537821e+00],
                             [3.55472805e-16, 1.77736401e+00, 3.46273023e-01, -2.03978904e+01],
                             [-3.13513815e-17, -1.56756906e-01, 7.64878236e-01, 4.96042520e+00],
                             [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00]])

# Create the original array with zeros
array = np.zeros(original_shape)
# Set the non-zero values at the specific index along the z-axis
z_index = 10 # Is gonna change on each iteration, but I put 10 as an example
array[:, :, z_index] = np.random.randint(2, size=(original_shape[0], original_shape[1]))

# Define a function to perform the resampling
def resample_array():
    return affine_transform(array, transform_matrix, resampled_shape, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0)

# Measure the execution time using timeit
execution_time = timeit.timeit(resample_array, number=1)

# Print the resampled array
print("Resampled array:")
print(resample_array())
# Print the execution time

print("Execution time: {:.2f} seconds".format(execution_time))
```

With this code, the resampling is taking around 0.15 seconds on my computer, which is way too much for what I want (we are doing this 50 times).
I already tried to just do a resampling of one slice like by doing it in this way

```
selected_slice = np.zeros([174,174,1])
selected_slice = array[:, :, z_index ] 
sliced_transform = affine_transform(selected_slice, transform_matrix, (112,112,1), order=1, mode='constant', cval=0)
New_array = np.zeros(resampled_shape)
New_array[:, : , z_index] = sliced_transform
```

But this for obvious reason (we are doing 3D resampling), wasn't giving me the same results than with the first method, so I couldn't go with this way.

So does any of you may have an idea to improved the time, while keeping the same results ?

Comment: AFAIK, `affine_transform` is not very optimized (actually slow in this specific case), but the alternative solution consisting in reimplementing it is very time consuming (and requires some optimization skills). While another library could certainly be used, this is off topic on S.O. You can open a scipy optimization issue but this will be a low prio issue.

Comment: Arf, that sounds bad... Otherwise, I was thinking to transform the 3D array, into a 1D array, and then do the resampling on a restricted part of this one. (By applying the differents coefficients of the zoom). Do you think that it would be possible ? 
Otherwise there is the possibility of multiprocessing, but with mac computer, everything is slow to start.

Comment: It depends of the case. (This code is used to create the mask used in the shimming of MRI). So sometimes this could be 0, or all of the element. How would you do, if you are doing this element by element ? 
Edit : I was answering a comment that was asking how many element are non zero in the slice

Comment: (previous comment was asking about how many items are non-zero. deleted because understood it better from question).  What about doing separate 2d interpolation for each non-zero z-slice? Then, depending on what you want to achieve, do n^2 linear/quadratic 1d interpolations along z-axis. Those 1d interpolations could be vectorized and also take into account that most of data is zeros

Comment: So by that you are saying after this step for example : 
`selected_slice = np.zeros([174,174,1])`

`selected_slice = array[:, :, z_index ] `

`sliced_transform = affine_transform(selected_slice, transform_matrix, (112,112,1), order=1, mode='constant', cval=0)`

`New_array = np.zeros(resampled_shape)`

Do an affine transformation on the z axis ? But at which index should I put the new slice ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, what are expected quality and characteristics of this resampling. Im suggesting doing resampling without using affine transform at all, not very high quality for sure.

Comment: What would matter in fact is just the indexes where the values are non zeros. So the quality doesn't matter that much if the non zeros indexes are the same. 
But Affine transformation is necessary because the images are not taken in the same spatial space

Comment: I am sure you can speed this up, I just not have enough experience with affine transforms to find some trick and use the fact there is a lot of zeros. What I could do and tried is multiprocesssing (answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got ~2.5x improvement using multiprocessing. Tested on 100 images

```
def resample_array():
    for _ in range(100):
        affine_transform(array, transform_matrix, resampled_shape, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0)


def single_resample(data):
    array, transform_matrix, resampled_shape = data
    affine_transform(array, transform_matrix, resampled_shape, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0)


def resample_array2():

    data_for_multiprocessing = []
    for _ in range(100):
        data_for_multiprocessing.append(
            [array, transform_matrix, resampled_shape]
        )
    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        results = pool.map(single_resample, data_for_multiprocessing)
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    execution_time1 = timeit.timeit(resample_array, number=1)
    execution_time2 = timeit.timeit(resample_array2, number=1)
    print("Execution time: {:.2f} seconds".format(execution_time1))
    print("Execution time multiprocessing: {:.2f} seconds".format(execution_time2))
```

```
Execution time: 4.39 seconds
Execution time multiprocessing: 1.62 seconds
```

Comment: This is one of the option, however with python being slow to start multiprocessing, I would prefer to not used it (in theory if it was fast to start, it would take half a second ) 
I don't know if this is because we are using scipy, but multiprocessing in this case is not optimal I think.  I used to use joblib mp for this,  but since python 3.9 it's very slow on mac bc we can't use the fork method anymore